# Disable neocomplete popup

Tags: vim, neocomplete

So I have a problem. I've installed `neocomplete` for vim and whenever it completes something for me, it leaves vim with that popup:

[image]

It's at the top of the `vim` screen, and it stays here, `ESCAPE` doesn't work for it. Is there a way to close this up, or better -> disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an actual window, so you'd close it like any other vim window (switch to it and `:q`, use `:on`, etc...). To disable this feature, add `set completeopt-=preview`to your vimrc and restart vim/resource your vimrc.